# SWI Prolog scalar multiplying with accumulators

Tags: list, prolog, reverse, accumulator

so I've been working on the following question:

> Write a 3-place predicate scalarMult whose first argument is an
>   integer, whose second argument is a list of integers, and whose third
>   argument is the result of scalar multiplying the second argument by
>   the first. For example, the query
>
> ```
> ?-  scalarMult(3,[2,7,4],Result).
> ```
>
> should yield
>
> ```
> Result = [6,21,12]
> ```
>
> Do this with the help of an accumulator and a wrapper predicate.

This is what I have done:

```
scalarMult(I, List1, List2):- scalarMult1(I, List1, [], List2).

scalarMult1(I,[], A, A).
scalarMult1(I,[H|T], A, Result):- H1 is H*I, scalarMult1(I,T,[H1|A],Result).
```

The only trouble with this is that it's putting the new elements at the head of the accumulator so I kind of end up with a reversed list (so for the example above, I would get Result  =  [12,21,6]). Is there any way I could work around this? I tried using reverse in my code but all my attempts fails.

Thanks

Comment: This isn't the answer to your question, so I'll just post it as a comment: the `maplist` based solution could look like, `scalar_mult(N, L, R) :- maplist(mul(N), L, R).  mul(X, Y, R) :- R is X * Y.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using reverse/2 works, actually:

```
scalarMult(I, List1, List2):- scalarMult1(I, List1, [], T), reverse(T, List2).
```

but I think the requirement to use an accumulator (really useless here) could be on purpose to verify your level of lists handling.

Comment: thank you. Could you please explain to me what is happening there? I tried this with both reverse(T,List2) and reverse(List2,T) and they both work. Why is that? And is it not more logical to use reverse(List2, T) as T would be the reversed list?

Comment: @user3281466, in the purest case, predicates in prolog are "relations" that describe the relationship between arguments, not functions with inputs and outputs. `reverse/2` is one of those purely relational prolog predicates that says "one list is the reverse of the other" and it doesn't matter which one you give it, the other will be the reverse. So both `reverse(T, List2)` and `reverse(List2, T)` will work. Not all predicates are purely relational. The prolog documentation indicates the behavior of arguments for each predicate (using `+`, `-`, and `?` indicators).

Answer (score 1):

Noting Carlo's remark about the use of accumulators being for didactical purposes, no accumulator is required for a straight-forward definition of the `scalar_multiplication/3` predicate (renamed from `scalarMult/3`; camel case is not considered good programming style in Prolog):

```
% first exchange argument orders to take advantage of the first-argument
% indexing that is provided in most Prolog implementations
scalar_multiplication(Scalar, Numbers, ScaledNumbers) :-
    scalar_multiplication_(Numbers, Scalar, ScaledNumbers).

% base case; either input list was empty or we finished traversing the list
scalar_multiplication_([], _, []).

% recursive case
scalar_multiplication_([Number| Numbers], Scalar, [ScaledNumber| ScaledNumbers]) :-
    ScaledNumber is Number * Scalar,
    scalar_multiplication_(Numbers, Scalar, ScaledNumbers).
```

This is an instance of a common pattern for processing lists. So common that several Prolog implementations provide a second-order predicate (or meta-predicate), usually named `map/3` or `maplist/3`, to handle it.